# blockwise cross-correlation in freq domain

Tags: matlab, cross-correlation

I have the following code in MATLAB to compute direct cross-correlation of 2 sequences x and y:

```
 clc
 clear

 x = rand(1,32);
 y = rand(1,32);

 N = length(x);

 nfft=2*N-1;


 % cross-correlation in freq domain
 xc_full_fd = fftshift(ifft( fft(x,nfft) .* conj(fft(y,nfft)) ));
```

The above result matches exactly with xcorr(x,y). Fine!
Now, I would like to do the same blockwise by taking 8 samples at a time from x and y. That is:

```
 clc
 clear

 x = rand(1,32);
 y = rand(1,32);

 x_1 = x(1:8);
 y_1 = y(1:8);
```

What should be my next steps in order to get get the same result as I do using the entire sequence? I am aware that I should carry out overlap-add method but I am not sure how many zeros should be appended to each block and what should be the overlap length bwtween adjacent blocks to achieve the same result as xcorr(x,y) ?
Please help me by extending the above code for block wise cross-correlation in freq domain.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just assign `nfft = 63`

Comment: @Yvon: nfft = 63 does not give same result. In practice I have x= rand(1,40000) and y = rand(1,40000). But at a time I can access only 128 samples and perform 256 point fft but at end should reproduce the same result as I get xcorr(x,y) using full 40000 samples. The above example is only a simplified version of this (reduced 40000 samples to 32 for simplicity).